# Why Cauchy's definition of infinitesimal is not widely used?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, math-history, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

[Cauchy defined infinitesimal as a variable or a function tending to zero, or as a null sequence.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CVRZEXFVsZkC&lpg=PA163&dq=cauchy%20infinitesimal%20discard&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q=cauchy%20infinitesimal%20discard&f=true)

While I found the definition is not so popular and nearly discarded in math according to the following statement.

(1). [Infinitesimal entry in  Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal#Variable_tending_to_zero):

> Some older textbooks use the term "infinitesimal" to refer to a
> variable or a function tending to zero

Why textbooks involved with the definition is said to be old ?

(2). Robert Goldblatt, Lectures on the Hyperreals: An Introduction to Nonstandard Analysis, P15
(His = Cauchy's)
[image]
Why says 'Even'?

(3). Abraham Robinson, Non-standard analysis, P276
[image]
why Cauchy's definition of infinitesimal, along with his 'basic approach' was superseded?

Besides, I found most of the Real analysis or Calculus textbooks, such as Principles of mathematical analysis(Rudin) and Introduction to Calculus and Analysis(Richard Courant , Fritz John), don't introduce Cauchy's definition of infinitesimal, Why ?
Why Cauchy's definition of infinitesimal was unpopular and not widely used, and nearly discarded?

P.S. I refered some papers still cannot find the answer.

Comment: Because the "equivalent" [epsilontic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) was considered, since the beginning of 19th Century, more rigorous.

Comment: Is Cauchy really giving a definition of an infintesimal there, or just the  idea of one. If two infintesimals tend to zero, in what sense are they different or the same? Is one bigger than the other in any sense?

Comment: For a modern reformulation, see e.g. Vladimir Zorich, [Mathematical Analysis I](https://books.google.it/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA137), Springer (2nd ed, 2016), page 137, for the definition : "function $f$ is said to be *infinitesimal compared with* the function $g$" and page 177 for the def of "a function $f : E → \mathbb R$ defined on a set $E ⊂ \mathbb R$ is *differentiable at a
point* $x ∈ E$".

Comment: @Paul Some books and papers says Cauchy did give the definition . Does different infintesimals matter ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! such infinitesimal is just an abbreviation for variables having limit to zero, does it make more contributions to mathematical analysis than the idea of limit ?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter what do you want to mean ?

Comment: If you know what "a variable tending to $0$" is you can call it an "infinitesimal", but you don't, nor do I. There are bound variables tending to $0$ under a limit sign, but there is no standalone mathematical object, like $\sin$, $\pi$, or a function $f:\>X\to Y$, that can be called "a variable tending to $0$".

Comment: @Ch, when you refer to "mathematical objects" you have in mind modern set-theoretic foundations.  however, Cauchy was not working with respect to these foundations as you know.  The OP is trying to understand Cauchy's definition and it seems anachronistic to impose modern views on historical developments. Besides, Cauchy does give an example of a variable tending to zero in his 1821 book, and it is recognizably a modern sequence (with limit $0$).

Answer (score 8):

You ask "why Cauchy's definition of infinitesimal, along with his 'basic approach' was superseded?"

The answer is that Cantor, Dedekind, Weierstrass and others developed a foundation for analysis to deal with certain difficulties related to Fourier series, uniform continuity, and uniform convergence. This development resulted in a formalisation that was a decisive moment in the history of analysis and was a great accomplishment. This is all well-known and rivers of ink have been spilt on the subject.

Yet the great accomplishment masked a significant failure that is less frequently spoken about.  Namely, these 19th century giants failed to formalize an aspect of the procedures of calculus and analysis that was ubiquitous until and including Cauchy, namely the notion of infinitesimal.  Instead, they provided infinitesimal-free *paraphrases* for the traditional definitions.  For example, Cauchy's lucid definition of continuity of $y=f(x)$ ("infinitesimal change in $x$ always leads to infinitesimal change in $y$") got replaced by the familiar jargon ("for every epsilon there exists a delta such that, if $|x-c|$ is less then delta, then $|f(x)-f(c)|$, etc.").

Not only did they fail to formalize it but, unable to do so, some of them became convinced that there was something wrong with the notion of infinitesimal itself, and from this jumped to the conclusion that infinitesimals must be inconsistent or self-contradictory. Cantor went as far as publishing an article claiming to "prove" that infinitesimals were inconsistent. In correspondence Cantor referred to infinitesimals as "paper numbers", "cholera bacillus of mathematics", and even "abomination"; the details can be found in

Dauben, Joseph Warren. Georg Cantor. His mathematics and philosophy of the infinite. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1990

and

Ehrlich, Philip. The rise of non-Archimedean mathematics and the roots of a misconception. I. The emergence of non-Archimedean systems of magnitudes. 
Arch. Hist. Exact Sci. 60 (2006),  no. 1, 1–121.

A solid set-theoretic formalisation for infinitesimals did not emerge until around 1960 and by then Weierstrassian paraphrases were solidly in place, making it difficult to overcome institutional inertia.

Cauchy's idea of representing an infinitesimal by a sequence tending to zero is basically valid, but needs some polishing. Cauchy's infinitesimal specifically is dealt with in a number of articles that you can find [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html).

Comment: Haha this is great, do you have sources for where Cantor referred to infinitesimals as those things?

Comment: Dauben's book on Cantor as well as P. Ehrlich's article from 2006. @enthdegree

Comment: Thanks very much ! Is the foundation for analysis they developed the completeness of the real numbers ?

Comment: The completeness of the real numbers takes a more intuitive form in the hyperreals.  Namely, it is equivalent to *the existence of the standard part function* on the set of finite hyperreals. Actually re-reading your comment I am not sure what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I actually want to ask "the foundation for analysis they developed is the completeness of the real numbers, right?"

Comment: Doyou mean to ask what exactly it is that they developed when people talk about such foundations? That's a good separate *question* that You might want to pose here! Keep me posted/

Comment: @iMath: those foundations were more about the $\epsilon, \delta$ definitions. Completeness has a different role to play in the traditional presentation of analysis (mainly it guarantees the existence of various limits and is the key to all significant theorems). But as Mikhail Katz mentions here, in non-standard analysis completeness is the key ingredient which allows us to get back to the reals after we have done some gymnastics with infinitesimals via the standard part function.

Answer (score 2):

Because Cauchy's formulation doesn't quite correspond to what we want it to be. For example, suppose $y$ is a function of $x$. Per Cauchy, we take $dx$ to be some decreasing value. What does that mean mathematically? Decreasing with respect to what? Evidently, $dx$ is to be a function of some other variable, which I'll call $t$. $dx = dx(t)$. Calling it a sequence as one of your quotes does just restricts the domain of $t$ to the natural numbers. The requirement on the function is that some appropriate limit with respect to $t$ of $dx(t)$ is $0$.

Now $dy$ is also some function of $t$, determined by the relationship between $y$ and $x$. In particular, $dy(t) = y(x + dx(t)) - y(x)$. Well and good, but by this definition, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$. That is not what we want. We want $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be the derivative, which is a function of $x$ alone. By the Cauchy definition,
$$y'(x) = \lim_t \frac{dy}{dx} \ne \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Since the latter depends on $t$.

So Cauchy's idea came closer to putting the idea on a solid foundation, but it still needed refining. Once suitable refinments were established, it has fallen out of favor.

Comment: Paul, I am not sure your answer is historically correct.  Cauchy clearly understood that when passing to the limit one needs to discard a higher order term, so this was not a shortcoming of his definition of infinitesimal.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - Thank you, but I never even hinted that Cauchy failed to understand this. After all, he is the one who invented what you call the "familiar jargon". At best, I may have been unclear in saying "By the Cauchy definition" when what I really meant was "Using Cauchy's concept of differentials, as I have interpreted it here". I was not addressing Cauchy's understanding of the subject, which of course was impeccable, but rather why i believe the informal description of differentials he provided is no longer used.

Comment: Paul, there is a common misconception that Cauchy invented the "familiar jargon" of epsilon-delta definitions.  This is not the case.  For example, in the case of continuity Cauchy gave an infinitesimal definition without mentioning epsilon-delta and without using alternating quantifiers.

Comment: As far as Cauchy's treatment of differentials, you got it exactly backwards.  While in definition of continuity Cauchy used infinitesimals, Cauchy defined the differentials in a recongnizably modern form.  Here $dx$ is an arbitrary number (not necessarily infinitesimal) and $dy$ is defined by the relation $dy=f'(x) dx$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - I'm sorry, but you are mistaken. Cauchy gave "definitions" which used infinitesimal language, in accordance with the language used by his predecessors. But when actually proving things, he reinterpreted them into the epsilon-delta formulation. When later writers actually wrote the definitions themselves in the epsilon-delta formulations, they were merely following what he used in his proofs. Cauchy originated the concepts, and even the use of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in their familiar roles.

Comment: I did not say Cauchy did not use such arguments.  There is a limited number of epsilon-delta style arguments in Cauchy's books but the explicit dependence of delta on epsilon is *never spelled out*.  It took several decades for Weierstrass to come up with the actual *definitions* involving alternating quantifiers. You will not find any alternating quantifiers in Cauchy.  As late as 1853, Cauchy used the infinitesimal definition of continuity in his paper that modified the condition of his sum theorem on *uniform convergence* to get a correct statement, improving on the 1821 version.

Comment: As for the "Cauchy differential", I was merely following the quotes provided in the OP. I am not familiar myself with how Cauchy described them. So when I refer to "Cauchy differentials" in the post and comments, I mean only what is attributed to Cauchy in the OP. Whether or not Cauchy is actually responsible for those, I cannot say.

Comment: ...You will not find any alternating quantifiers in Cauchy's 1853 research paper, either.

Comment: If you are not familiar with Cauchy's work firsthand, what are you basing yourself on concerning epsilon-delta definitions?

Comment: Though I do not have the source readily available, I have read proofs from directly from Cauchy using epsilon-delta, and have read his definitions of continuity and limits. I have not read his definitions of differentials themselves, but this doesn't mean I am somehow completely ignorant of any parts of his body of work. In the proofs I have seen, he used epsilons and deltas exactly as they are used today. All Weierstrass or his predecessors did was to break with tradition and actually define matters in this way.

Comment: Paul, I am glad to see that you have seen the primary sources on this.  I would be very interested in a specific argument where Cauchy uses epsilon-delta "exactly the way it is used today". The arguments that I have seen never specify an explicit dependence of delta on epsilon. On the other hand, there is a wealth of work by Cauchy where he uses infinitesimals to prove results ranging from elasticity to integral geometry, with not a whiff of either epsilon or delta.

Comment: Note that the quotation from Robinson conveniently provided by @iMath neatly summarizes Cauchy's role in the history of analysis.  Alas, it is often lost in the rattle of historians attempting to present the history of analysis as an inevitable march toward Weierstrassian epsilontics.

Comment: For what you've argue with @MikhailKatz , you should first read the paper http://norvaisa.lt/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Borovik-Katz-2011.pdf if you are interested in.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I am still interested in reaching a consensus on this aspect of Cauchy's work.  I summarized my thoughts [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/cauchy.html); see if you care to respond.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not remember the source. As I recall, it was a paper about the origin of the epsilon-delta idea. They quoted two proofs of Cauchy in Latin and translated (I don't know latin, so I rely on the translation). I remember distinctly noting that the proof used epsilon and delta just as I was familiar with using them. The verbiage may not have explicitly said "for all" or "there exists", (I don't recall exactly), but he started with an $\epsilon$, then picked a $\delta$ that made the inequality hold, which makes those quantifiers and their order implicit, anyway.

Comment: I believe I actually found the paper from a link in a post on this site, but I do not remember what the post was about. For my comments on your thoughts. Berkeley obviously found something deficient, per his famous quote. Again I know nothing about Cauchy's differentials, so cannot discuss those. And I believe in math freedom: Any math that is consistent is good math, worth studying. So more power to you for arguing for differentials. Just don't dismiss the other approach either.

Answer (score 2):

Robinson's definition of infinitesimal can be seen as a refinement of Cauchy's.  In Robinson's definition, a hyperreal number is an equivalence class of sequences of real numbers, and it's a key theorem (for the relationship between standard and nonstandard analysis) that such a hyperreal number is infinitesimal (in the ordering that Robinson defines) if and only if any/all of the convergent sequences in its equivalence class converge to zero.  (The equivalence class will also have some divergent sequences, although zero will still be a cluster point of all of them.)  If we formalize a "variable" that converges to zero as a sequence that converges to zero, then every infinitesimal in Cauchy's sense gives rise to an infinitesimal in Robinson's sense.

Not everything is the same.  I expect that if you presented Cauchy with $x = (-1)^n/n$ as a variable that converges to zero (as $n \to \infty$), then he might accept that as defining a nonzero infinitesimal that is neither positive nor negative.  But every nonzero hyperreal number is either positive or negative.  The choice of free ultrafilter used in Robinson's construction of hyperreals determines whether the hyperreal associated to this particular sequence is positive or negative (it is definitely nonzero), and that is completely arbitrary.  But it must be one or the other.

I suppose that one would argue that $x = (-1)^n/n$ is simply not going to be useful in any argument with infinitesimals, and certainly Cauchy usually worked with infinitesimal variables such as $x = 1/n$ (which is definitely positive).  But I don't know that Cauchy would never find it useful or that every argument of Cauchy's can be directly translated into an argument in Robinson's nonstandard calculus.

Comment: Possibly Cauchy's definition is closer to the work of Schmieden-Laugwitz which exploited the Frechet filter instead.

Comment: Interesting!  I had not known about Schmieden & Laugwitz, but I see that Laugwitz has a chapter on it (modestly attributed entirely to Schmieden in the chapter title) in Reuniting the Antipodes.  (I have just read most of this chapter on Google Books.)  By the way, Laugwitz states at one point ‘there exist oscillatory infinitesimals’ (which are neither positive, negative, nor zero) in what he calls ‘the Cauchy continuum’.